# Append the word "and" to the last element in a list?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a list: "Apples, Eggs, Milk", but I would like to append the word "and " to the last element so it reads "Apples, Eggs, and Milk".

Here's what I've come up with, but I seem to be hitting a wall, and the livedoc Adobe documentation site is down (which usually has helpful examples).

```
<cfset VARIABLES.shoppingList= ListInsertAt(VARIABLES.shoppingList, ListLen(VARIABLES.shoppingList),'and')>
```

The result is:

"Apples, Eggs, and, Milk" unfortunately. Maybe ListInsertAt isn't the right method for this?

Comment: I think that instead of adding it to the list, you should rather add this "and" upon rendering of the list, replacing the last comma (cause there shouldn't be a comma if there's an "and")

Comment: @Bartdude It's perfectly fine to leave the comma there - both options are grammatically correct.

Comment: It seems that it's a problem someone has already solved: [CFLib: ListAddAnd](http://cflib.org/udf/listAddAnd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use `listSetAt` to modify the last item.

```
<cfset variables.shoppinglist = listsetat(variables.shoppinglist, listlen(variables.shoppinglist), "and " & listlast(variables.shoppinglist))>
```

Answer (score 2):

Internally, a list is just a [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Why not use regex to replace the last occurrence of a comma?

Surely this is more efficient than converting the string to an array, looping, injecting another string into the array, then converting everything back to a string again.

You're simply modifying a string. No need to bring arrays, loops, conditions or a ton of list methods into it.

```
<cfset variables.shoppinglist = reReplace(variables.shoppinglist, ",([^,]*)$", " and \1")>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to add "and" to the last element in the list i would convert it to an array and change the last array item. Or like bartdude said, leave it out of the list until you display it

```
<cfset shoppingList = "Apples, Eggs, Milk">
<cfset shoppingList = ListToArray(shoppingList)>
<cfset shoppingList[arrayLen(shoppingList)] = "and " & shoppingList[arrayLen(shoppingList)]>
<cfset shoppingList = ArrayToList(shoppingList)>
```

Or to do it on display:

```
<cfset shoppingList = "Apples, Eggs, Milk">
<cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(shoppingList)#" index="i">
<cfif i gt 1>
    <cfif i eq listLen(shoppingList)>, and<cfelse>,</cfif>
</cfif>
<cfoutput>#listGetAt(shoppingList,i)#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Also, if the coldfusion docs are down. You can use [www.cfquickdocs.com](http://www.cfquickdocs.com).